# Can I get my (byte-)string back?

Tags: haskell, marshalling

Given a binary format that involves `VarInt`s. That is integers with a size varying binary representation, is it possible to run a parallel parser that checksums everything that I just read?

Example:

A simple structure would be parsed like this:

```
getFoo :: Get (VarInt, VarInt)
getFoo = (,) <$> getVarInt <*> getVarInt
```

**Edit:** `VarInt` is just a newtype around `Int`. It is parsed like this:

(see section 1.2 of http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format.txt)

```
getVarInt :: Get VarInt
getVarInt = go 0
    where go i = do

        h <- fromIntegral <$> getWord8

        if not $ testBit h 7
          then return (h .&. 0x7F)
          else do
            t <- go (i+1)
            return $ h .|. (t `shiftL` (i * 7))
```

Now some structures have a CRC32 checksum at the end. If the size of the structure would be known beforehand I could easily `lookAhead` and run the checksum on that:

```
getFooCRC :: CRC32 -> Get (Int, Int)
getFooCRC expected = do
  crc <- crc32 <$> lookAhead (getBytes 8)
  when (crc /= expected) $ fail "checksum doesn't match"
  (,) <$> get <*> get
```

Now ... how would I handle this if I were to parse the same structure containing `VarInt`s?

**Note:** I am using the [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) library, but the same probably applies to [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) and similiar libraries.

Comment: Which library is your `VarInt` type defined in?

Comment: @MichaelSteele None. Internally I just use a regular `Integer`. The encoding is described in section 1.2 of this document: http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format.txt

Comment: What you need is a running total of consumed bytes. It looks like "cereal" doesn't keep track of that for you. You could write a helper function to calculate the number of bytes a given `VarInt` occupies. You could make a new data type such as `data EncodedVarInt = EncodedVarInt VarInt Int` with a `Get` instance, and fill the `Int` as you decode. The "binary" library does keep track of consumed bytes which would make things a little easier.